# Horizontal and Vertical Scroll on iFrame - ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, scrollbar, overflow

Hey I'm building a webpage that contains an iFrame in all other browsers it appears fine but when testing in ie7 I get a vertical and horizontal scrollbar, is there anyway to remove this?

```
<div id="converter3"><iframe src="https://postoffice.travelmoneyonline.co.uk/widget/(S(lwtb0t45hyhwv2z5sarusa45))/default.aspx
" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrollbars="no" style="height:279px; overflow:hidden;"></iframe></div>


#converter3{
    float:right;
    width:218px;
    margin-right:12px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: please... post... some... code.

Answer (score 0):

Try appling these:

- `overflow: hidden;` in CSS style for the `<iframe>`
- `scrollbars="no"` as `<iframe>` attribute

So:

```
<iframe scrollbars="no" style="overflow: hidden;" ... >
```

Comment: Hey I gave that a go but still no luck have updated my original post with my code

Comment: Finally got it working by doing the following - <iframe src="https://postoffice.travelmoneyonline.co.uk/widget/(S(lwtb0t45hyhwv2z5sarusa45))/default.aspx
" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrollbars="no" style="height:279px; width:260px; overflow:hidden; position:relative;margin-right: -15px; margin-bottom: -15px;"></iframe>

Comment: Good :-) Accept my answer if it helped. Bye.